# Writes to Cloud Firestore (emulator) is not showing in Cloud Functions emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I am using Firebase Hosting/Firestore/Functions for a Vue app. Hosting + Firestore are working fine. 
Now I wanna add more functionality and wanted to add Functions. To test locally, I initiated a Firestore and can run all 3 emulators. 
Now, when I start the emulators and goto the hosting emulator, I can insert a record, which also shows up in production database, but the function is not triggered. It's onCreate. 
I deployed the function and it works fine. I can see the console.log().

Why are local/production writes not triggering the cloud function?

Here is the function:

```
export const sendWelcomeEmail = functions.firestore.document('/activeJobsTestDB/{jobId}').onCreate((data,context) => {
  const inputRecord = data.data();
  console.log('here' + inputRecord);
  // const mailOptions = { 
  //   from: '"Spammy Corp." <noreply@firebase.com>',
  //   to: inputRecord.email,
  // };

});
```

```
i  Starting emulators: ["functions","firestore","hosting"]
⚠  Your requested "node" version "8" doesn't match your global version "12"
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  firestore: Serving ALL traffic (including WebChannel) on http://localhost:8080
⚠  firestore: Support for WebChannel on a separate port (8081) is DEPRECATED and will go away soon. Please use port above instead.
i  firestore: Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
✔  firestore: Emulator started at http://localhost:8080
i  firestore: For testing set FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: dist
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
✔  hosting: Emulator started at http://localhost:5000
i  functions: Watching "/Volumes/Work/playground/sforce-job/sforce-jobs/functions" for Cloud Functions...
>  here
✔  functions[sendWelcomeEmail]: firestore function initialized.
✔  All emulators started, it is now safe to connect.
```

I goto localhost:5000 and can use my app as I want, but the function is not triggered. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to trigger a local cloud function with writes to production Cloud Firestore?  That will not work.  If you want to connect your local web app to the Firestore emulator, see this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype#instrument_your_app_to_talk_to_the_emulators

Comment: Thanks @SamStern. Yes, I realised it will not work and I have to create a local mock database. I am currently creating a json which represents DocumentSnapshot and then pushing it via function shell to ensure it is working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you have more questions about how to use the emulators please file an issue on the firebase-tools GitHub repo!

Comment: @SamStern: Thanks man! No I don't have more issues. I am stubbing data myself.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself here in case someone faces this: I realised there is no way to connect Cloud Firestore with local Cloud Function. Easy way to do it is to have a json which looks like DocumentSnapshot and then pass it to the function via shell. Use:

```
firebase function:shell
var data = require('./testData.json');
sendwelcomeEmail(data)
```

Other way will be to create a local database in firestore emulator, point the cloud function to look at firestore emulator.
Then run hosting emulator and all 3 should play well nicely.